# login not possible even after putting in the correct values

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined index: username in C:\wamp\www\Website\storeadmin\admin_login.php..and the same for password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224291/undefined-index-username-in-c-wamp-www-website-storeadmin-admin-login-php-and)

```
//admin_login.php
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["member"])){
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
}

?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){     // <-  Check the user has clicked the button
  $manager = preg_replace('#[A-Za-z0-9]#i',"",$_POST["username"]);
  $password = preg_replace('#[A-Za-z0-9]#i',"",$_POST["password"]);



include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username ='$manager' AND password ='$password'LIMIT 1");
$exist_count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($exist_count == 1){
    while(mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id = $row["id"];
        }

    $_SESSION["id"]= $id;
    $_SESSION["manager"]= $manager;
    $_SESSION["password"]= $password;
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();

    }
    else{
    echo 'This information is incorrect,try again <a href = "index.php">Click Here</a>';
    exit();
    }
}




?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> AdminLogin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>

<body>
<div  id="mainWrapper" > 
    <?php include_once("../template_header.php");?>
    <div id="pageContent" > 
    <div align="left" "style="margin-left:040px;"><h1>Please login to continue</h1><br />
    </div>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="admin_login.php"> 
    UserName<br />
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="40"/>
    Password<br />
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="40"/> 
    <br />
    <br />
    <br /> 
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="LogIn"/>  
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php include_once("../template_header.php");?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
//index.php
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["member"])){
    header("location:admin_login.php");
    exit();
}

$managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i',"",$_SESSION["id"]);
$manager = preg_replace('#[A-Za-z0-9]#i',"",$_SESSION["manager"]);
$password = preg_replace('#[A-Za-z0-9]#i',"",$_SESSION["password"]);


include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id ='managerID' AND username ='$manager' AND password ='$password'LIMIT 1");
$exist_count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($exist_count == 0){
    echo("Your login session data in not in the database");
    exit();
}



?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Service Admin Area</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>

<body>
<div  id="mainWrapper" > 
    <?php include_once("../template_header.php");?>
    <div id="pageContent" > 
    <div align="left" "style="margin-left:040px;"><h1>Hello Store Manager .What would you loke to do today</h1><br />
    <h3><a href="inventory_list.php">Manage Inventory</a></h3><br/><h3><a href="">Manage Me</a></h3><br/></div></div>
    <?php include_once("../template_header.php");?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem i am facing is that i am not able to login to my index.php page even after i have put in the correct username and password as specified in my database which i have set through phpmyadmin.Everytime i try to login it invokes the [echo 'This information is incorrect,try again Click Here'] as mentioned in the admin_login.php.I am getting a bit frustrated.Can you help me out guys?

Comment: Are you getting an error message when you run that query? Try adding some debugging, and see what happens.

Comment: why are you emptying your variables before you use them? those preg_replace's will just turn the $_POST vars in to ""

Comment: @andrewsi ..I am not getting any query related errors.

Comment: Actually, SO is for specific questions, it's not a place for debugging your (or even not your!) code (what it's becoming more and more last year)... And, there are a lot of tutorials over the Network about PHP/MySQL authorization.

Comment: Also, please stop using the mysql_* functions, they are being deprecated. No new code should be written with them. Use something that supports prepared statements like PDO or the mysqli_* functions.

Comment: @user1485323 - what does your generated SQL query look like? Does it work properly when you run it directly in the database?

Comment: @nathan Removing the preg_replace brings me back to the admin_login.php....but not the index.php that that i want it to go to.

Comment: @andrewsi Yes the both the SQL querys in both the above pages run perfectly fine.As i said i removed the preg replace,but then why does it not lead me to my index.php,when my input data is ok.Instead it leads back to the same admin_login page?

Comment: What is the function of preg_replace in this code?

Comment: @Ashwini Dhekane to filter out only the required characters

Comment: Then I think your regex should be '#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i'

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you use the preg_replace. Looks to me you are clearing the variables. Which explains why you cant find yourself in the database. Try to remove the preg_replace and see what happens. Also when you when you the SQL query you forgot a space between your password and limit.

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: @Stefan..Removing the preg_replace brings me back to the admin_login.php....but not the index.php that that i want it to go to.